# Dojo request won't call callback

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm useing dojo for a project. In there I have an ajax request to the server. The URL I provide is valid, and I'm getting data from URL. Also, I've checked in the Browser if the request is send, and how it responses. But the callback isn't executed at all... . Here is the code:

```
require([
            "dojox/grid/EnhancedGrid",
            "dojo/store/Memory",
            "dojo/store/JsonRest",
            "dojo/store/Cache",
            "dojo/data/ObjectStore",
            "dojo/request",
            // a few other things i require
            "dojo/domReady!"
        ], function(EnhancedGrid, Memory, JsonRest, Cache, ObjectStore, request, query, on, dom, parser, registry, cookie, json, array, button, attr, lang) {
        request.get("<?=  base_url(); ?>c_fremdkosten/get_list",
            {
                handleAs: "json"
            }
        ).then(function(data){
            console.log(data); //is NOT executed...
        });
});
```

Has somebody an idea?

Comment: Did you post your entire code ? If so you miss a `});` at the end.

Comment: It is not the entire code, it is just a snippet, but I will change it here anyway, thanks

Comment: I solved it. It had something to do with the data I get. I got a "ä" in my object as a fieldname and this isn't working... .